# get key json oject in lua

Tags: json, lua

Good morning,

How in the file below I can retrieve the value of each object.
I manage to recover the value of the other objects (id,date..) but I block to recover the values located in the key data:numTracking and the url.

```
[
   {
    "id": "644b7d34e35a1ed30c071372",
    "date": "2023-04-28T08:00:52+00:00",
    "reference": "644b7d2c0ee3f48b9603abba",
    "merchantReference": "000545671",
    "type": "Expedition",
    "code": "expedition_shipping",
    "data": {
        "numTracking": "CMP000545671-LX",
        "urlTracking": "https:\/\/fulfillment"
     }
   },
]

this is the code I started
valuer1 = "000545671"
tag1 = "merchantReference"
tag2 = "numTracking"

function getData(jsonFile, tag1, value1, tag2)
local file = io.open(jsonFile, "r")
local content = file:read("*all")
file:close()
local data = json.decode(content)
  for i, item in ipairs(data) do
  if item[tag1] == value1 then
  tracking = item[tag2] 
  end
   if item[tag1] ~= value1 then
  end
  end
  return tracking
end
```

Comment: Does `json.decode(content)[1].data.numTracking` work?

Comment: Where to recover? `data` is already a table that contains the the keys and the values.